# How to select N last members in javascript array (functional style)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Is there an elegant built-in (functional style) way to select last `N` members in Javascript array?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
list.slice( -N );
```